# Using several included php pages, how do I make a layout?

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to learn PHP (being a C# programmer) and so far it has not been difficult (getting db records, logging in...), but the thing I thought would be easy actually is not, for me - I learned to use the "include" keyword to inject the content of other files. However, I cannot figure out how to influence the design, where I would like to get the database records in the left sidebar (for that I wrote sidebar.php that does the querying, and page.php that is meant to show details, so that is the main content element):

```
<?php
   include('session.php');
?>
<html">
   
   <head>
      <title>My catalogue</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
   </body>
   //I would need this to be always on the left
  <?php include("sidelist.php"); ?>
  //This should be the main content of the page
  <?php include("page.php"); ?>
   
</html>
```

I did search around but all advice just stated to use the include, which certainly is not all that is needed.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Simply use DIV tags to set the layout, then put the include inside the DIV

Comment: Have a look for a template engine (I've used Twig in the past) as they tend to built for this sort of thing.  They also can help as there are tutorials on how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you are talking about layouts you will be dealing with HTML and CSS.

wrap your two includes in divs and then create some css class to format the layout as you need e.g

```
<?php
   include('session.php');
?>
<html">
   
   <head>
      <title>My catalogue</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
   </body>
   //I would need this to be always on the left
  <div id="sidelist">
  <?php include("sidelist.php"); ?>
  </div>
  //This should be the main content of the page
  <div id="main">
  <?php include("page.php"); ?>
  </div>
   
</html>
```

And then the CSS might look like

```
#sidelist{
float:left;
width:75%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#main{
float:left;
width:25%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! If I may ask one more thing (not truly related): I have added a top navigation bar, how do I easily change the content of the page.php base on the selection in the menu?

Comment: Either (1) change to a different PHP page on selection of different item of the menu, or (2) pass a different parameter (e.g. <a href=page.php?content=123>Page 123</a>) and then the page.php to use the $_GET["content"] to determine what contents to load and display.